# Listing all commits on a branch that happened between two commits

Tags: git

I have two commits on the master branch. These commits are results of merges from different branches. For example 3 different branches were merged into develop which was later merged into staging which was then merged into master.

- Commit1: 5707a585
- Commit2: 95c4f15c

I would like to know the age of the commits included inside `5707a585` that were not present inside `95c4f15c`.

Basically what I would like to know is how long it took from the time something was committed for the first time on a working branch to get to `5707a585` (when a production deploy was run) if it was not inside `95c4f15c`, in order to measure our dev team throughput - how long it takes for code changes to get to production.

I am not really comfortable with git and don't know how no idea how to approach this, so any help is appreciated. I tried using `[git-rev-list][1]` in the following way: `git rev-list 5707a585...95c4f15c` but don't know if the list of commits I get is the correct one or not (since I am getting 14 commits).

I also tried `git log master --since="$(git log -1 5707a585 --pretty=%ad)" --until="$(git log -1 95c4f15c --pretty=%ad)"`, which gives me a lot more commits but also includes commits that came between the initial commit and the target (master) branch.

Comment: How about `git log 5707a585..95c4f15c`?